# Understanding a piece of RSpec code in a Rail application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

So in the `Rpsec` code I see somethings like this so I guess we are just kind of initializing variables for our test in here:

```
  let(:base_uri) { 'http://127.0.0.1' }
  let(:tenant_id) { 'tenant_id' }
  let(:client) { PersonSearch::Client.new(base_uri, tenant_id) }
  let(:mock_http) { double('Net::HTTP') }
  let(:mock_request) { double('Net::HTTP::Get') }
  let(:mock_response) { double('HTTPResponse') }
  let(:path) { "/people/search?#{ params.to_param }" }
```

Then for example in a test I have seeing something like this:

```
context 'default parameters' do
let(:params) { { search_query: 'a', page: client.default_page, page_size: client.default_page_size } }
let(:mock_results) do
  PersonSearchServicesHelper.create_mock_person_search_result(client.default_page_size).to_json
end

it 'uses default params when options are missing' do
  client.stub(:create_http_request).and_return([mock_http, mock_request])
  client.stub(:request).and_return(mock_response)
  client.should_receive(:create_http_request).with(:get, path, {})
  client.should_receive(:request).with(mock_http, mock_request, client.retry_on).once

  mock_response.stub(:body).and_return(mock_results)
```

My biggest thing that I "don't get it" is the ".stub" parts. Can someone please exaplain it a little more that why we did that and what is happening with it?  Also if there are documentation links I can refer to, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/method-stubs and https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

These are what are known as [test stubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub); stand-ins for methods on the object with pre-defined responses.

Think of `stub` as a shorter way to overwrite an object's method, instead of:

```
def client.create_http_request
  [mock_http, mock_request]
end
```

For more information on the nuances between: mocks, stubs, and fakes have a read over http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html and http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html